# how to pass data from save function to server in MySQL using API call

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I am new to Angular 2&4, when I am trying to connect angular4 with MySQL using HTTP.post method. The values are not passing to API/save in server.js. Can anyone please help how to insert data into MySQL from angular4.
I am getting an error at server.js.

app.component.html

```
<main class="content">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">UserName: </label>
          <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="person.username" class="form-control" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password: </label>
          <input type="text" name="password" [(ngModel)]="person.password" class="form-control" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()" >Save</button>
      </div>
  </form> 
</main>
```

app.component.js

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public person: any;

      public constructor(private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location) {
          this.person = {
              "username": "",
              "password": ""
          };
      }

      public ngOnInit() {}

      public save() {
        console.log("save function starts");
          let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
          console.log("save function middle"+ JSON.stringify(this.person));

          this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/save", JSON.stringify(this.person), options)
              .map(result => result.json())
              .subscribe(results => {
                  this.location.back();
              }, error => {
                  console.error(error);
              });
      }
  }
```

server.js

```
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var postsModel = require('./models/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql      = require('mysql2');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'Speckle'
  });
  var app = express();

  connection.connect(function(err){
  if(!err) {
      console.log("Database is connected ... nn");    
  } else {
      console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");    
  }
  });
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
   });

  app.post("/api/save",function(req, res) {
    console.log("request"+ req.body.username);
     postsModel.save(req.body);
    });
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "")));
app.listen(3000);
```

posts.js

```
var database = require('./database');

exports.save = function (params) {
    return database.query("INSERT INTO login SET ?", params)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log("save");
            return result.insertusername;
        });
};
```

database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var connection;

exports.init = function (config) {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
};

exports.query = function (sql, params) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("SQL statement" + sql);
        console.log("sql"+sql +""+"params" +params.username+params.password);
        connection.query(sql, params, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }

            resolve(result);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: You don't have to `stringify` json data. But if you want to `stringify` it you should `parse` it to JSON at the server side.

Comment: what is that error?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public save() {
        console.log("save function starts");
          let data = this.person;

          this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/save",data)
              .map(result => result.json())
              .subscribe(results => {
                  this.location.back();
              }, error => {
                  console.error(error);
              });
      }
```

Comment: i replaced with your code ,but still getting sane error at server.js

Comment: can you post any error log you are getting? or any request is going actually? at least the pre-flight OPTION request?

Comment: Values are not passing to app.post('/api/save',(req,res){}) 
ERROR:
request[object Object]
SQL statementINSERT INTO login SET ?
sqlStatement --> INSERT INTO login SET ?params-->undefinedundefined
(node:29047) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
(node:29047) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: leave about backend node code for now... check network tab of browser and see if the request is properly going.. if all the payload is going fine then it might be the issue with node code.

Comment: i verified all the requests are properly passing

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()" >Save</button>
```

you can go with this.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save(person)" >Save</button>

public save(person) {
        console.log("save function starts");
          let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
          console.log("save function middle"+ JSON.stringify(this.person));

          this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/save", JSON.stringify(person), options)
              .map(result => result.json())
              .subscribe(results => {
                  this.location.back();
              }, error => {
                  console.error(error);
              });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are performing `stringify` JSON data and at the server side you doesn't parse it to the JSON. However at requests you don't have to `stringify` it becasuse you can just sent JSON data without any errors. But If you want to send stringified JSON you have to parse it to JSON to use it as `param.login or param.password`, without this you are just refering to the `string` to non-existing property. So after you send data you should perform on data `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Can you please help me to solve the issue, i removed stringify in http.post method. but still getting same issue, can you please correct at what position i am missing